# инспекция кода random'айзера

Tags: html, css, инспекция-кода

Данный код генерирует числа из введённого диапазона. Можете показать на ошибки в коде, и как его можно улучшить.

```js
function rand(){
let num = Math.random()
let maxval = max.value
let minval = min.value

label.innerHTML = Math.round(num * (maxval - minval) + minval)
}
```

```css
body{
background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);
}
table{
width: 50%;
height: 50%;

margin: 25%;
}
input{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
label{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
button{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th><input id="min" valuetype="number" ></th></tr>
<tr><th><input id="max" valuetype="number" ></th></tr>
<tr><th><label id="label" >0</label></th></tr>
<tr><th><button onclick="rand()">generate</button></th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Я посоветовал бы следующее: **1.** Забыть как верстать на табличной вёрстке (таблицы - только для таблиц). **2.** Доработать скрипт, допив условие `if(!min) min = 0`. **3.** Подумать над оформлением визуальной части.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Можно использовать [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) для разметки.
2. Использовать функцию как инструмент для получения числа от `min` до `max`, а не для получения и вывода в конкретное место.
3. Добавить проверки для пустых полей
4. Слушать нажатие на кнопку в javascript, а не в атрибутах html, js для логики, html для отображения.

```js
const label = document.querySelector('.result');
const button = document.querySelector('.button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const min = document.querySelector('.min').value;
  const max = document.querySelector('.max').value;

  if (min !== '' && max !== '') {
    label.innerHTML = randomize(min, max);
  };
});

function randomize(min, max) {
  const random = Math.random(min, max);
  return Math.round(random * (max - min) + max);
};
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);
}

.form {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.result {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input type="number" class="min" />
  <input type="number" class="max" />
  <button class="button">Randomize</button>
  
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```